# How FIN scan type actually works?

Tags: networking, tcp

I have googled many times about **How FIN scan works?** But always I got the same answer and i.e. **"(In short) It is used to bypass the basic filters and it uses the FIN flag to determine the Closed | Open Ports."**

And what the FIN flag is? **"FIN flag is used for to making an ending for the sender to send more packets"**

**And here How it works?**

> If the listening port in the target is closed then it will reply back to the RST message. The negotiation is shown below,
>
> Attacker will send ƒ  FIN
>
> Target will respond with ƒ  RST
>
> If the listening port is open then the target will not send any
>   response back. The negotiation is shown below,
>
> Attacker will send ƒ  FIN
>
> Target response ƒ  none

*Now my doubt arises from here.*

**Why the target host will respond the RST packet? Why not others? And even it closes it reply with RST packet.**

**And When it Open it didn't reply? What is actually going behind the scene which I got totally missing?**

**Now this is What the first thing I want to know? (& the other one is How this bypass the basic filters)**

Comment: Because that's what it says in RFC 793.

Comment: No @EJP I want to know in a technical way, what actually happens in FIN scan type?

Comment: The answer is still in RFC 793. Off topic.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what [*RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) says TCP must do:

> Reset Generation
>
> **As a general rule, reset (RST) must be sent whenever a segment arrives which apparently is not intended for the current connection.**
> A reset must not be sent if it is not clear that this is the case.
>
> There are three groups of states:
>
> 1. If the connection does not exist (CLOSED) then a reset is sent in
>    response to any incoming segment except another reset.  In
>    particular, SYNs addressed to a non-existent connection are rejected
>    by this means.
>
>    If the incoming segment has an ACK field, the reset takes its
>    sequence number from the ACK field of the segment, otherwise the
>    reset has sequence number zero and the ACK field is set to the sum
>    of the sequence number and segment length of the incoming segment.
>    The connection remains in the CLOSED state.
> 2. If the connection is in any non-synchronized state (LISTEN,
>    SYN-SENT, SYN-RECEIVED), and the incoming segment acknowledges
>    something not yet sent (the segment carries an unacceptable ACK), or
>    if an incoming segment has a security level or compartment which
>    does not exactly match the level and compartment requested for the
>    connection, a reset is sent.
>
>    If our SYN has not been acknowledged and the precedence level of the
>    incoming segment is higher than the precedence level requested then
>    either raise the local precedence level (if allowed by the user and
>    the system) or send a reset; or if the precedence level of the
>    incoming segment is lower than the precedence level requested then
>    continue as if the precedence matched exactly (if the remote TCP
>    cannot raise the precedence level to match ours this will be
>    detected in the next segment it sends, and the connection will be
>    terminated then).  If our SYN has been acknowledged (perhaps in this
>    incoming segment) the precedence level of the incoming segment must
>    match the local precedence level exactly, if it does not a reset
>    must be sent.
>
>    If the incoming segment has an ACK field, the reset takes its
>    sequence number from the ACK field of the segment, otherwise the
>    reset has sequence number zero and the ACK field is set to the sum
>    of the sequence number and segment length of the incoming segment.
>    The connection remains in the same state.
> 3. If the connection is in a synchronized state (ESTABLISHED,
>    FIN-WAIT-1, FIN-WAIT-2, CLOSE-WAIT, CLOSING, LAST-ACK, TIME-WAIT),
>    any unacceptable segment (out of window sequence number or
>    unacceptible acknowledgment number) must elicit only an empty
>    acknowledgment segment containing the current send-sequence number
>    and an acknowledgment indicating the next sequence number expected
>    to be received, and the connection remains in the same state.
>
>    If an incoming segment has a security level, or compartment, or
>    precedence which does not exactly match the level, and compartment,
>    and precedence requested for the connection,a reset is sent and
>    connection goes to the CLOSED state.  The reset takes its sequence
>    number from the ACK field of the incoming segment.